# How to read image data?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to create an application that receives an image with only black and white tiles. White tiles would mean a space that you can move in, while black tile would be a space that you can't move in (a wall maybe)

In this image i want to define a starting point and a goal point (maybe with diferent colors, red and yellow) so I can study pathfinding problems

How can I read an image and process the information it has in it?

It would be sometinhg like that: [image]

Here I'm able to define walls, starting point, goal point in an image and I'd like to read it's data. How can I do that in python?

Comment: Can the imagine instead be encoded as a text file? You would save yourself a lot of headaches if you aren't reading and processing an actual image file.

Comment: You mean with 1's and 0's? Yeah.. this way I think I know how to do. But I'd like to work with images. Draw my brand new maze and make it solve on it's own, do you get it?

Comment: Why don't you use pygame or something similar to "draw" these tiles then solve them like that, you could start with all white tiles, then click the tiles you want to be solid, then solve

Comment: That can be a solution indeed. Do you know any links that could guide me through this? Pygame is a huge library..

Comment: You could also use PiL (Python Image Library) to load your image and read the individual pixels.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SciPy library](http://www.scipy.org/), which comes with many [image processing tools](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/):

```py
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread("lena.bmp")
```

You can easily access a pixel, e.g. at row 10 and column 15:

```
print img[10, 15]
```

Output:

```
[188 101  71]
```

(In this example I'm using the "Lena" test image from [here](http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp).)

---

Depending on the image format you might want to convert it from an RGB color image to gray-scale:

```
img = img.mean(axis = 2)
print img[10, 15]
```

Output:

```
120.0
```

---

If you need to scale the `uint8` pixel values to the range [0..1]:

```
img = (img / 255).round()
print img[10, 15], img[10, 6]
```

Output:

```
0.0 1.0
```

Comment: is it too hard to recognize shapes from an image? For example: recognize squares so that I can make each one my maze's tiles

Comment: @RodrigoAlves: Yes, it is. There is a whole field of research on [Pattern Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition). You might find solutions for very specific problems (well defined image conditions, limited set of shapes etc.), but no general shape recognition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image module from the PIL library (which you will need to install) then do something like:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("PATH TO IMAGE", "MODE (probably 'r')")
pixel = image.getpixel((x,y))
```

x,y are the pixel coordinates, and you can get the color of that pixel.